# Avoid redirect to /index.php on Laravel 4

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4

I'm running a Laravel 4 project, and when I hit in the browser www.mydomain.com all goes well, but when I hit mydomain.com I am redirected to www.mydomain.com/index.php.

Can someone help me to avoid this redirect to index.php?

Here is my .htaccess on public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My app is hosted on fortrabbit.com and my domain is parked on a shared host of mine from where I made my dns settings. I will provide you with other details if neccessary. Thank you!

Comment: Somewhere in your system there is a rule/code that does `non-www => www` redirect. That rule is firing after above internal rule.

Comment: I think that was the problem. Thanks! :)